# Trying to Curl an image into S3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I have this so far.  But I just cant seem to get it to work.

```
$ch = curl_init('https://urlofIMAGEIwanttoretrieve.php');
$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
fwrite($fp, $data);

$s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
$filename = sha1(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')).".jpg";
$s3->put('products/large/'.$filename, $fp, 'public');
```

This uploads the file fine, but its 0 bytes.

and if I do

```
$file = Image::make($fp)->encode('jpg');
$s3->put('products/large/'.$filename, $file, 'public');
```

I get

```
Unable to init from given binary data.
```

How can I just curl an image from a PHP url, straight into S3

Comment: Have you found any solution for this ? if so please answer the question since I have same issue here

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP memory wrapper to store the contents of the image, and use`$s3->putObjectFile()` method:

Method 1:

```
   $ch = curl_init('https://urlofIMAGEIwanttoretrieve.php');
    $fp = fopen('php://temp', 'wb');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    fwrite($fp, $data);

    $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
    $filename = sha1(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')).".jpg";
    $s3->put('products/large/'.$filename, file_get_contents($fp), 'public');
```

Method 2 :

```
$ch = curl_init('https://urlofIMAGEIwanttoretrieve.php');
$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
fwrite($fp, $data);

$s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
$filename = sha1(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')).".jpg";
$s3->put('products/large/'.$filename, $fp->__toString(), 'public');
```

Method 3:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://urlofIMAGEIwanttoretrieve.php');
    $fp = fopen('php://temp', 'wb');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    fwrite($fp, $data);

    $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
    $filename = sha1(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')).".jpg";
    $fp  = $fp->stream();
    $s3->put('products/large/'.$filename, $fp->__toString(), 'public');
```

Comment: I found this exact answer already.  Not really sure how to use that with the Laravel Storage class though.  putObject is not a method on it

Comment: @KyleK, let me read the documentation then.. could you add content type in your current code?

Comment: Looks like theres a putFile method Storage::putFile('photos', new File('/path/to/photo'));  which allows for "streaming" of file?  Not sure if thats what I need.

Comment: I just viewed this : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpPHP.html.

There's still using putobject.

Comment: Im not using S3 sdk directly.  Im using Laravel's Storage class, which is a multipurpose wrapper of sorts

Comment: @KyleK, ah that explains.. and i've just edited the answer and like you to try it out.

Comment: putObjectFile is also not a method on the Storage class in Laravel.  The uploading part is not really the part Im having an issue with anyways.  Its more the file, and how to actually first get it into a good format to upload.  The upload is "working", its just empty 0 bytes.  I just need to get $fp to actually be a file somehow.  (base64_encode maybe? I dont know)

Comment: @KyleK, try these 2 methods.. The method you did correct just conversion part it failed.

Comment: @KyleK, added another 1 method.. i think the last one would work on laravel 5.

Comment: None of these methods work.  Method 1 gives me "file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given".  Method 2 give me "Call to a member function __toString() on resource" and 3 gives me "Call to a member function stream() on resource "